# Force Revit files to go through Navis conversion

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-navisworks

There is a bug in the Revit model parsing that causes viewer items to show and hide and not be selectable. I remember someone telling me once that I could force model derivative to use the Navis parser in place of the Revit as a workaround. Anyone know hoe to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The feature is not in production yet but you will be able to switch to another IFC exported when submitting a Model Derivative job:

```
{
  "input": {
    "urn": <your-model-urn>
  },
  "output": {
    "formats": [{
      "type": "svf",
      "views": ["2d", "3d"],
      "advanced": {
        "switchLoader": true
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Petr. So it's the switchLoader that will fore the MD job to use Navis? This is causing issues in production today, any ideas when this will be available?

Comment: The plan is to have this option switch to the new extractor for a period of time (couple of months), and then use the new extractor by default.

Comment: As far as the ETA to prod, I don’t know. Please stay tuned to the Forge blog - we’ll likely announce the option in a quick blog post.

Comment: UPDATE: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-pipeline-call-change
in case anyone comes across this answer in the future.